# Decorate a black-box method on an existing object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

Is there a way to decorate a method on an object as a black-box?

Consider this: my company develops and tests in Windows (and coworkers will frequently put the code on network drives). I have a DataFrame I want to save that dumps its status in the middle of a script, but Windows loves file-locking, so if I (or anyone else) has that file open, the entire script fails.

Instead, consider this would-be decorator:

```py
import time
def softWrite(funcObject, func):
    @wraps(func)
    def tryTryAgain(*args, **kwargs):
        while True:
            try:
                # It's a method on the object that would normally take "self" so supply "self" somehow?
                return func(funcObject, *args, **kwargs)
            except PermissionError:
                print("File is locked, trying again in 5 seconds")
                time.sleep(5)
```

Then every time I wanted to write a dataframe, I could just decorate it:

```py
@softWrite
df.to_csv("myData.csv", quoting= csv.QUOTE_ALL)
# some stuff
@softWrite
df.to_parquet("myDataLater.parquet", index= False)
# more stuff
@softWrite
df.to_excel("myDataFinally.xlsx")
# Oh now I'm writing something with a Path object
@softWrite
myPath.write_text("Some awesome contents")
```

Note that these are on **existing objects with attached methods**, not standalone functions.  Further, manually ovewriting each of a classes's internal methods that may or may not be used to write out up front, just so that when *I* instance the object it has it attached, is not sufficient (besides being an ugly, heavy lift) -- say I got the DataFrame from [datatable](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/frame/to_pandas.html) or [pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.to_pandas.html); suddenly import *order* becomes fragile.

Needless to say I could do this if it were my own function, or if I rolled my own Pandas, or whatever, but that's insane overkill. And writing a try/except loop for every write out for any program or script that may touch a Windows file is insane.

This seems like an obvious use case, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You must wrap the method itself not the return value of the method call

```
import csv
from functools import wraps
import time
from pandas import DataFrame


def softWrite(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def tryTryAgain(*args, **kwargs):
        while True:
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except PermissionError:
                print("File is locked, trying again in 5 seconds")
                time.sleep(5)

    return tryTryAgain


df = DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4])
df.to_csv_try_again = softWrite(df.to_csv)

df.to_csv_try_again("myData.csv", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Note: this changes the method only on the instance of the object, you could also `DataFrame.to_csv_try_again = softWrite(DataFrame.to_csv)` to apply to all instances of DataFrame

Comment: I did explicitly say

"Further, manually overwriting each of a classes's internal methods [...] is not sufficient"

so you're suggesting that no solution like what I'm asking for exists?